# MODX empty dashboard

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I'm using MODX the first time and it all worked since yesterday. I didn't change anything and the dashboard and the package manager worked without any problems but since yesterday I couldn't see the dashboard itself, just the top navigation menu in the backend/admin manager and the left sidebar menu with the ressources, elements and file tabs. Besides this empty dashboard the package manager doesn't work too. It just shows the table headings like name, version, release etc. without a table body.

I think that maybe the MODX Rest API is broken?
My package manager source was http://rest.modx.com/extras/ and it worked a few days ago.
I also tried http://rest.modxcms.com/extras/ already but it doesn't work too (returns a 404).

I'm using MODX Revolution 2.2.6pl and I also didn't change anything on the server configuration, so allow_url_open and curl still is enabled in my PHP 5.2.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as though you are not able to connect to the MODX rest server. http://rest.modx.com/extras/ will not return anything in your browser. It is currently running. I have confirmed both on an external site and a localhost site and had no problem connecting to the server. You may be better served asking for help at the [MODX forums](http://forums.modx.com)

Answer (score 6):

I am facing the same issues with the blank backend - what is your hoster? 
I am at strato.

You can disable the "compress_css" and "compress_js" than it's working again.

You can find this in the

```
/core/cache/system_settings/config_cache.php
```

find

```
'compress_css' => '1',
'compress_js' => '1',
```

and set it to:

```
 'compress_css' => '0',
  'compress_js' => '0',
```

after you can enter the backend again: very important --> go directly to your system settings and search for "compress" - turn of again the `compress_js` and `compress_css`.

Now it'll work. I struggled around with it...:-)

AD

Comment: I was skeptical, but this just worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: This will be overwritten if you clear the cache. You must also update the settings in the database, either through the manager, or if it isn't working, directly in the table, eg, `UPDATE \`intiwara_modx\`.\`modx_system_settings\` SET \`value\` = '0' WHERE \`modx_system_settings\`.\`key\` = 'compress_css';` and likewise for `compress_js`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the dashboard and package manager that do not work? or is it everything in the manager?

some basic modx troubleshooting:
- clear the cache first, anything weird happens, clear the cache before you do anything, if for some reason you can't clear it in the manager - delete everything under /core/cache/ and while you are at it check that the webserver user can write to that directory [/core/cache/]
- turn up tour error logging in system settings and see what the error log has to say
- enable php logging & check your webserver logs
- turn off css & js compression in your system settings [you may have to edit the database table to do this as well]

Check your php settings again, I've had trouble [in the past] with Plesk apache restarts 're-applying' default php settings that I have changed [safe mode, session paths etc]

If you didn't fiddle with modx, then it's most likely going to be cache or a change in environment.